# How can I find a dynamic number in a long NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a very big `NSString`, which holds around 1500 characters in it. In this string I need to extract a phone number, which may change frequently, as it is a dynamic data. The phone number will be in the format of `251-221-2000`, how can I extract this?

Comment: Check [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSScanner)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this previous question on regular expressions and `NSString`.

[Search through NSString using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expressio)

In your case an appropriate regular expression would be `@"\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}"`.

Comment: how to convert the result as string as i am getting output as:  <NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x8ab2b20>{2134, 12}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x8ab2480> \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} 0x1}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707187/regex-to-extract-all-the-substrings-between-two-charachters-or-tags

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for a regular expression.  You can use the `NSRegularExpression` class to achieve this.  You can test your regular expression at http://www.regextester.com

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourString = @"Your 1500 characters string ";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}"
options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
// your code to handle matches here
}];
```

Let me know it is working or not.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in the regexp