# Regular expression to extract href url

Tags: regex, swift

I want to extract the links from a String with regular expressions. I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763865/regular-expression-in-ios-to-extract-href-url-and-discard-rest-of-anchor-tag) and I tried this code

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>.*?</a>")
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
        let htmlLessString :String = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: text,
                                                                            options: [],
                                                                            range:range ,
                                                                            withTemplate: "")
```

but the proposed regular expression deleted all the content of the `href` tag. My string look like

```
SOME stirng  <a href="https://com.mywebsite.com/yfgvh/f23/fsd" rel="DFGHJ"> some text I need to keep </a> and other text
```

and the expected result is

```
SOME stirng  https://com.mywebsite.com/yfgvh/f23/fsd some text I need to keep and other text
```

the perfect result is

```
SOME stirng some text I need to keep (https://com.mywebsite.com/yfgvh/f23/fsd) and other text
```

Do you have an idea if it's possible to achieve this?

Comment: As you use Groupings (because I think you wanna keep the string). Why dont you use nstextcheckingresult 
 - https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstextcheckingresult now loop through your matches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707187/regex-to-extract-all-the-substrings-between-two-charachters-or-tags as you can see here and only replace the prefix "<a[^>]+href=\"" at the suffix "\"[^>]*>.*?</a>"" ?

Comment: This is built-in functionality with `NSDataDetector`. Have you tried using that rather than building your own regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not regular developer of Swift, but, Did you tried to use the `withTemplate`option of `stringByReplacingMatches` like this?

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>(.*)?</a>")
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
        let htmlLessString :String = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: 
                                                                 text,
                                                                 options: [], 
                                                                 range:range ,
                                                                 withTemplate: @"$2 ($1)")
```

Comment: Thanks, this keep the url but delete the text between <a> and </a>

Comment: You're welcome! To mark your perfect result try `withTemplate: @"($1)"` and remember mark as resolved when you double check it! haha

Comment: Sure but as I wrote in the comment, this solution don't keep the text between <a> and </a>

Comment: Ouch, I didn't noticed that, it should be fixed if you change the regex for this one `"<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>"` and also change `withTemplate: @"$2 $1"`

Answer (score 4):

Of course it deletes the `href` content because you are *...ReplacingMatches...with* empty string.

Your sample string does not match the pattern because the closing tag `</a>` is missing.

The pattern `"<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>"` checks until a closing angle bracket after the link.

The captured group is located at index 1 of the match. This code prints all extracted links:

```
let text = "<a href=\"https://com.mywebsite.com/yfgvh/f23/fsd\" rel=\"DFGHJ\">"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>")
let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
let matches = regex.matches(in: text, range: range)
for match in matches {
    let htmlLessString = (text as NSString).substring(with: match.rangeAt(1))
    print(htmlLessString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to work in this case: `href="(.*)" .*">(.*)<\/a>(.*)` , group 1 would have your url , group 2 text between `<a></a>` and group 3 text after `<a></a>` , however you will have to use this extension to be able to get information out of groups, as there is no native group support: http://samwize.com/2016/07/21/how-to-capture-multiple-groups-in-a-regex-with-swift/